# Prove that $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable if $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}, \ X^{-1}\big( [t, \infty)\big) \in \mathcal{A}$.

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, proof-writing

**Definition:** $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable if $\forall B\in \mathcal{B}$ we have that $X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}$ $\ $(where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{A}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of the probability triple).

My book states that the condition "$\forall B\in \mathcal{B}, \ X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B}$" is equivalent to $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}, \ X^{-1}\big( [t, \infty)\big) \in \mathcal{A}$. They hint at the idea that such intervals generate $\mathcal{B}$ , and that if $X^{-1}(B')\in\mathcal{A} \ $ for all members $B'$ of a generating set of $\mathcal{B}$, then the condition $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A} \ $ holds for all members of $\mathcal{B}$.

I understand why such intervals generate Borel's $\sigma$-algebra, but I'm having trouble showing that it's sufficient for the condition to hold on a generating set for it to hold in general. I was hoping someone could point me to a proof.

I'd appreaciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a fairly common result, should be able to google it easily.  A rough draft:

Let L be collection of all sets B such that X^{-1}(B) is in sigma algebra A.  Obviously all your intervals are in L.  You can show L is a sigma algebra easily.  The set theoretic inverse preserves all the properties you need.

So L is a sigma algebra that contains your intervals.  But since the Borel sigma algebra is generated by the intervals (so smallest sigma algebra that’s contains the intervals) it must be that the Borel sigma algebra is subset of L.